# Stationarity and moving standard deviation

Tags: standard-deviation, stationarity, moving-window

Suppose $\{X_t\}$ is stationary process. We observe a sample of $N$ observations from the process, i.e., $x_1, x_2, ..., x_N$. The stationarity property implies that the distribution doesn't change over time. Does this imply also the following?

- We divide the sample consisting of $N$ observations into $k$ subsamples with $n$ observations in each (i.e., $n\times k = N$). Then we calculate standard deviation for each subsample. Does stationarity imply that the estimates of standard deviation for the subsamples will be equal (or quite close)?
- Is it reasonable to define a moving (or rolling) standard deviation for a stationary process?
- If no, then how to distinguish between high/low volatile regimes in the $\{X_t\}$ process? (i.e., $\{X_t\}$ shows volatility clustering, and there is a need to distinguish high volatile clusters from low volatile).